# Android App Hangs in production

Tags: android, performance, freeze

I am doing a Retrofit call and using sync-adapter.

My app is available on Google PlayStore. Very few times users are reporting app hang while I am trying to generate issue but no success.

What is best you identify issue?

Comment: You might be performing some heavy task on main thread. Identify the code that takes more time and execute it in an asynctask

Comment: It happens only few time and not happening on my 512 RAM phone, I am using Loader manager to load data on list and retrofit to do server call. Is there any specific tool which can track issue

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand your question just go to android studio's **Android Monitor** and then select **memory** near to your **logcat** than you will see when your Application consumes more memory that cause hangs.

so enjoy your code time.